# Power BI gateway admin

Tags: powerbi, gateway

### Context

I need to start sharing Power BI reports with other users (all users are Power BI Pro licenses).

Reports will be in live connection with an Analysis Services and my original data source are on-premise, therefore, I need to install a gateway to transfer data into the cloud.

### Question

We already have a capable server for installing the gateway, therefore, my questions are:

1. Is it wise to install a Gateway VM on that server even though the server is used for other applications?
2. I don't have access to Power BI Admin Portal and it is tricky to get access to it since we are a very big company all over the world. Can I use an on premises data gateway without a Power BI Admin account? (While installing gateway just adding my account as admin)

Comment: (1) Are you working with Azure Analysis Services or Analysis Service on-premise? (2) what other applications is you server used for? (3) How many GB of data you need to transfer and how many times a day?

Comment: (1) Not really sure to be honest. What I'm doing is connecting to a SQL server with Power BI Desktop using Direct Query. Making the report and publishing to "My workspace". From there I will just share those reports with different users. Need a gateway so they could access this data without having access to our SQL server on their own. ( Read only ).  (2) Other applications like personnel management tools with SSMS, some web applications and more which I can't think of now. (3) There are not many reports at this moment which aren't very large either so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I was already given a VM with 8 cores, 8gb ram and 120gb SSD so that'll do just fine. So I'm guessing I don't really need a BI admin portal access to be able to successfully share those reports.( about 20 people, ca 10 reports in total shared to right persons ) Right?

Comment: (1) Therefore you are not in Live Connection but Direct Query. In this specific scenario, if you have a Premium Capacity in your Workspace you would not need to install a Gateway server because you have one already available in your Premium Capacity. (2) OK (3) If you already have a VM available and you only work with PBI (no analysis services), you might need to change settings only in your Power BI Service.

Comment: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/ from your feedbacks, you would need the standard more. Here the instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem

Comment: We don't have premium. I am sharing those reports with users who own PRO license. These users do not have access to our SQL server and we're not going to give all of them access. What I need is for them to see fresh data, let's say updated everyday once automatically. The server I am talking about is our own, nothing to do with power bi premium. It's just a server that is 24/7 online so the gateway would be online aswell 24/7